# version control

Tags: version-control

We need a system that allows multiple admins and developers to make changes in salesforce meta data and merge them while resolving conflicts in an automated by as possible.

Anyone have good free solutions?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

One solution could be a server with [GIT](http://git-scm.com/) (version controlling) and [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) (continuous integration):

```
SFDC <N---1> GIT/Jenikins machine <1---N> Local (admin/administrator) machine
```

The simplified procedure:
The metadata is pulled from the Salesforce to the GIT. Each user works with an individual branch and committed changes to the master. Then changes are deployed back to the Salesforce.

Related topics:

- [Setting Up Jenkins for Force.com Continuous Integration](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2013/03/setting-up-jenkins-for-force-com-continuous-integration.html)
- [Force.com CI Using AWS, Github and Jenkins](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_CI_Using_AWS,_Github_and_Jenkins)
- [Jenkins Setup for Salesforce.com Automated Deployment](http://javednehal.blogspot.de/2014/05/jenkins-setup-for-sfdc-and-github.html)